# Limit to how many fields a '*' can hold in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have wasted about two hours messing around with character field lengths in my data to get around an error about 'Right truncation of string data' turns out it seems to be to do with the table '*' function.

It appears as if this operator can only hold a certain number of fields before throwing an error. Does any anyone know if this is the case? I am working on a large series of tables with hundreds of columns and manually stating them at each step in my job makes maintenance much more difficult. If this is a know issue, is there a way around it?

Comment: `*` is simply returning all columns, you might get an error indicating that you hit the limit of 2018 columns, but never *2893 Right truncation of string data*. This is an ANSI session mode error caused by assigning a longer string to a shorter (Var)Char column, e.g.`'1234'` -> CHAR(3).

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of Teradata are limited to 2048 columns per table. 
To check database limits please refer to “SQL Reference: Fundamentals, Appendix C”.

If that is not your case, please provide some more info with your measurements.